# How do I apply SharePoint web service to return ModifiedBy, TimeLastModified, UniqueID and FileType for a document?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, ssis

I am currently successfully applying C# code via a SharePoint web service (http://company.name.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx) in an SSIS Task (SQL Server 2008 RS) to check in and check out files in various folders on a SharePoint site (2010) using the input of URL values like that shown below.  However, I now have a new task for a separate set of documents in SharePoint applying the same environment.  I must also gather the name of the user who last modified each document, the time it was last modified, the SharePoint Unique ID, and file type.  I am using the SharePoint web service because the database service is located on a different server than the SharePoint server.

For each document I have a unique URL path, such as:

> http://company.name.com/a/abc/projects/Project_1.xls
>   http://company.name.com/b/def/projects/Project_4.xls

Can somebody provide a simple C# example of retrieving (not updating) the four attributes of interest using SharePoint webservices for a document posted on a SharePoint site given a URL value like one of those listed above?  A console application example would be fine, since it is similar to a SSIS task script.

If it will assist, I've provided below the code for checking in and checking out files in a SSIS script task.  Prior to setting up the code, I added a Web Reference called SharePointListsService applying the Web Reference URL "http://community.teamcomcast.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx".

```
SharePointListsService.Lists listService = new SharePointListsService.Lists();
listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

//Check out a file in SharePoint using the URL
string fileCheckout = "http://company.name.com/a/abc/projects/Project_1.xls";
bool myResults = listService.CheckOutFile(fileCheckout, "true", DateTime.Now.ToString("f"));

//Check in a file in SharePoint using the URL
string fileCheckin = "http://company.name.com/a/abc/projects/Project_1.xls"
myResults = listService.CheckInFile(fileCheckin, "Completed revision.", "0");
```

With the above code as an example, can somebody provide me with a similar code example using C# and SharePoint web services that returns the following attributes for a given URL for a file?

```
ModifiedBy
TimeLastModified
UniqueID
FileType
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com). Without seeing an example of your code, it is very difficult for anyone here to identify how best to begin helping you.

Comment: Troy, I have not been able to try anything since I do not know where to begin.  That is why I am requesting help.  Otherwise, I would not be asking for help in the first place.  I've provided an example code for another purpose that also applies the SharePoint web service.

Comment: Awesome - that's a great help. My point wasn't that your question was bad - just that people on this site tend to get better answers more quickly by clearly stating what they've tried and then asking increasingly specific questions. :) Big improvement just from putting up what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great workaround to the tedious code that would have otherwise been necessary.  The following link provides a means to down load an adapter and documention for applying it.  The adapter integrates SSIS and SharePoint.  That is, it will allow you to add a SharePoint Source and SharePoint Destination task items under Tools that can be used to pull information from SharePoint almost the same as you would from a database or Excel file.  I've set it up and it's working great.

http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652

Using the adapter I can capture the attributes (Author, Modified By, Last Modified, and so forth) associated with one or more documents posted on SharePoint source and easily send the values to either a new SharePoint destination or Excel or database destination.